# Pagination with specific search type on ElasticSearch

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

We are currently using ElasticSearch 6.7 and have a huge amount of data making some request taking too much time.
To avoid this problem, we want to set up pagination within our research towards elasticsearch. The problem is that I can't put one of the pagination methods proposed by ES on the different requests that already exist.
For example, this request contains different aggregations and a query:
https://github.com/trackit/trackit/blob/master/usageReports/lambda/es_request_constructor.go#L61-L75
In addition, the results are sorted after the information is collected.

I tried to set up the Search After method as well as a form of pagination using `from` & `size`.
Scroll doesn't works with aggregations and composite aggregation doesn't accept query.

So, there is any good way to do pagination in ElasticSearch combined with other request type and how to do it with the example above?

Comment: Seems like you can change your mappings a little bit, from what i have learned, your mapping should be optimized according to your search use cases, not according to your data, ideally, u shouldn't need to do any operation at query time, that's the whole point of keeping a flat nested structure unlike relational database

Answer (score 1):

> composite aggregation doesn't accept query

It does accept query. In the example below, the results are filtered based on play_name. The aggregation only get applied to the result of the query and it can be paginated using the `after` option.

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "play_name": "A Winters Tale"
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "speaker": {
            "composite": {
                "after": {
                    "product": "FLORIZEL"
                },
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "product": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "speaker"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "speech_number": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "speech_number"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "line_id": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "line_id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How am I supposed to add composite to a request like this? https://pastebin.com/NQuyEtGW

Comment: @clement-trackit you can use sub aggregations refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_sub_aggregations